# Многоуровневая HTML форма с вкладками

Tags: html, массивы, форма, вкладки

Столкнулся со сложностью реализации подобной формы, прошу помочь советом.

Пояснения к рисунку:

1. Это календарь событий в единой форме, где можно добавлять месяцы, даты и события.
2. При нажатии на январь и 28  соот. кнопки становятся зелеными, высвечиваются события проснулся утром, поел в обед, лег спать.
3. При клике на февраль и 7 - видим соот. события

Вопросы:

1. Понимаю как реализовать frontend часть через метод .append(), но не могу понять по архитектуре.
2. Где будет находится зеленая ветка января с несохраненным input event3 «Здесь я пишу что-то сейчас», когда я щелкну на февраль и 7. Или когда нажму на + у месяцев. Создавать многослойный  друг над другом и управлять ими через z-index?  Может есть решение поизящней?
3. Как построить архитектуру serializeArray() при отправке формы? Я подписал name у каждого элемента, но не уверен что правильно. И мне точно нужен serializeArray() ?
4. Может есть плагины? Проект на Wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Ну, скорее всего, с точки зрения архитектуры, это не верное решение, но я бы сделал так: для месяца и для дат поставить "чекеры", т.е., выбран ли какой-то
   месяц и дата.
2. Далее сделал бы запрос на сервер (Допустим, через ajax), который вернул бы мне список каких-то дел (Событий) в этот день (В виде JSON массива (Не забываем пропарсить)). Далее сделал бы ОДНУ модалку (Или что вы там используете для отображения событий за какую-то дату) и выводил бы туда весь этот список дел (Событий).
3. > Где будет находится зеленая ветка января с несохраненным input event3 «Здесь я пишу что-то сейчас», когда я щелкну на февраль и 7. Или когда нажму на + у месяцев

Нигде. Это можно просто не сохранять, я думаю, что пользователь привыкнет к этому. хаха)

Или можно это всё же сделать в модалке (Как я писал выше) и настроить обработчик (Что-то типа jQuery.change или других). При закрытии делаем запрос на сервер с просьбой сохранить то, что сейчас должно быть закрыто

4. > Как построить архитектуру serializeArray() при отправке формы? Я подписал name у каждого элемента, но не уверен что правильно. И мне точно нужен serializeArray()?

Просто скажу, что я в этом не уверен, что оно вам нужно. То самое и про name. Лучше пробуйте смотреть в сторону [jQuery селекторов по Id](https://xn----7sbbaqhlkm9ah9aiq.net/news-new/selektori-jquery.html#t8).

5. > Может есть плагины? Проект на Wordpress

Можете попробовать и так, но тут главное помнить, если вы хотите, что бы оно выглядело максимально классно, то вы просто задолбаетесь играться и разбираться в этом плагине, т.к. это точно будет сложные, а не просто два скрипта и три функции)

Comment: За ночь надумал аж 4 варианта, что скажете? 

1. При нажатии на + создается новая форма на каждом уровне вложенности. Форму обзываем по имени родителя
2. Сохранять каждое заполненное поле по on.change() (что-то наподобие Google таблиц), где нет кнопки сохранить
3. Создание вкладок по каждому клику на + и наложение по z-index/схлопывание до 0 высоты, ширины/переключения
4. При добавлении нового месяца и дня сохранять предыдущую ветку не спрашивая пользователя

Comment: @Rickie, в принципе, хороший вариант, но я бы на вашем месте отказался бы от z-index'а в сторону более сложной работы со скриптами

Comment: Еще вариант сериализировать форму по клику на месяц/день, сохранять в переменную и конкатенировать с сериализацией следующей вкладки

Comment: @Rickie, скажем так, что вариантов реализации много, по этому пробуйте. Как вы и просили, направление я дал вам :D